# CouchDB View With OR Condition

Tags: database, couchdb

I have two kinds of documents in couchDB with following json type:

```
1. 
{
 "_id": "4a91f3e8-616a-431d-8199-ace00055763d",
 "_rev": "2-9105188217acd506251c98cd4566e788",
 "Vehicle": {
     "type": "STRING",
     "name": "Vehicle",
     "value": "12345"       
 },
"Start": {
     "type": "DATE",
     "name": "Start",
     "value": "2014-09-10T11:19:00.000Z"      
 }
}

2. 
{
   "_id": "4a91f3e8-616a-431d-8199-ace00055763d",
   "_rev": "2-9105188217acd506251c98cd4566e788",
   "Equipment": {
       "type": "STRING",
       "name": "Equipment",
       "value": "12345"       
   },
"Start": {
   "type": "DATE",
   "name": "Start",
   "value": "2014-09-10T11:19:00.000Z"      
 }
}
```

I want to make one view which search all these documents whose doc.Vehicle.value=12345 OR doc.Equipment.value=12345.
How can I make this view that will return all these kind of documents.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it isn't possible for you to have two documents with the same `_id` and `_rev` values in the same database.  Is this just a cut and paste error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just emit both (yes, map functions may emits multiple times different key-values for the same doc) values with your view:

```
function(doc){
  if (doc.Equipment) {
    emit(doc.Equipment.value, null)
  }
  if (doc.Vehicle) {
    emit(doc.Vehicle.value, null)
  }
}
```

And request them by the same key:

```
http://localhost:5984/db/_design/ddoc/_view/by_equip_value?key="12345"
```

See also the [Guide to Views](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/) for more info about CouchDB views.

Answer (score 1):

With Kxepals Version, you cannot query the type of results ("12345" can be either Vehicle, OR Equipment). you can only see the result when you use "include_docs=true" and search inside the doc, or make a second query with the id of the results.

If you want to see the type (or Query by type) you need to extend the View : 
..

```
if(doc.Equipment) {
  emit (doc.Equipment.value,doc.Equipment.name);
}
if(doc.Vehicle) {
 emit(doc.Vehicle.value,doc.Vehicle.name);
}
```

Here, the name is the value of the result rows.

But you can also define the results in the query, if you put the name as a first query item:

```
if(doc.Equipment) {
  emit([doc.Equipment.name,doc.Equipment.value],null);
}
if(doc.Vehicle) {
  emit ([doc.Vehicle.name,doc.Vehicle.value],null);
}
```

Here, the 
Your Query for Vehicles:

```
 /viewname?startkey=["Vehicle"]&Endkey=["Vehicle",{}]
```

Equipment:

```
/viewname?startkey=["Equipment"]&endkey=["Equipment,{}]
```

Here, the name is the first Item of the result rows key array.

Maybe this will help : http://de.slideshare.net/okurow/couchdb-mapreduce-13321353

BTW: Better solution would be :

```
{
 "_id": "4a91f3e8-616a-431d-8199-ace00055763d",
 "_rev": "2-9105188217acd506251c98cd4566e788",
 "type": "Vehicle",
 "value":"12345",
"Start": {
     "type": "DATE",
     "name": "Start", // ? maybe also obsolete, because already inside "Start" Element
     "value": "2014-09-10T11:19:00.000Z"      
 }
}

{
 "_id": "4a91f3e8-616a-431d-8199-ace00055763d",
 "_rev": "2-9105188217acd506251c98cd4566e788",
 "type": "Equipment",
 "value":"12345",
"Start": {
     "type": "DATE",
     "name": "Start", // ? maybe also obsolete, because already inside "Start" Element
     "value": "2014-09-10T11:19:00.000Z"      
 }
}
```

in this case you can use only one emit:

```
emit([doc.type,doc.value],null)
```